# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user of: it.besmart.models.Park

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having a problem in a Controller. I'm using spring mvc and security with hibernate.

I have two model classes:

User.java and Park.java which have a ManyToMany bidirectional relation.
With this relation I link one or more Park to a User. I need to list Parks for the logged-in user. So, in my Park.controller I have a method which grabs the logged username

```
@RequestMapping(value = { path }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listParks(ModelMap model){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
        User user = userService.findBySso(name);
        logger.debug("Username = "+name);
        logger.debug("User = "+user.toString());
        List<Park> parks = parkService.findParkByUser(user);
        String pageTitle ="Elenco Park";
        model.addAttribute("parks", parks);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", pageTitle);
        model.addAttribute("cssActivePark", cssActivePark);
        return path+"/parks";
    }
```

`List<Park> parks = parkService.findParkByUser(user)`should return the list of the Parks for a User. In **ParkDaoImpl** this method, recalled by ParkServiceImpl, is

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Park> findParkByUser(User user) {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        if(user != null){

            criteria.createAlias("user", "users");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("users", user);
        }
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
            List <Park> parks = criteria.list();

        return parks;
    }
```

I'm getting, while listing the Park, this exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user of: it.besmart.models.Park
...

root cause

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user of: it.besmart.models.Park
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.getType(EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.java:57)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:245)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:229)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:112)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:88)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1663)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    it.besmart.dao.ParkDaoImpl.findParkByUser(ParkDaoImpl.java:62)
    it.besmart.service.ParkServiceImpl.findParkByUser(ParkServiceImpl.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3792.findParkByUser(Unknown Source)
    it.besmart.controller.ParkController.listParks(ParkController.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:118)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

This are the model part of the ManyToMany relation

In User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="users_parcheggio", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="park_id") })
    private Set<Park> parks = new HashSet<Park>();

    public Set<Park> getParks() {
        return parks;
    }

    public void setParks(Set<Park> parks){
        this.parks = parks;
    }
```

And in Park.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="users_parcheggio", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="park_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="user_id") })
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the `alias` wrong. If you check the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you will see that the ordering of your parameters here:

```
if(user != null){
    criteria.createAlias("user", "users");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("users", user);
}
```

is incorrect. It should read:

```
if(user != null){
    criteria.createAlias("users", "u");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u", user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i got as exception this message `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: u of: it.besmart.models.Park`

Comment: Can you post your code here? Just those two lines that you changed.

Comment: `if (user != null){
   criteria.createAlias("users", "u");
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u", user));
  }`

Comment: I solved it, thanks @Gergely Bacso I changed the ParkDaoImpl method not passing the object `user` but it's id, in this way `criteria.createAlias("users", "u");
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u.id", userId));`

Comment: Sorry, I could not get back to you on this. But it is good news that it is resolved then.